# PHP ftp_put via SSL

Tags: php, ssl, ftps

One of our suppliers has requested we change from an ftp to ftps for sending them files.

I have a PHP script that uses ftp_connect to transfer the files.

I've modified the script to now use ftp_ssl_connect and while it can open the connection and login, it fails to transfer the files.

This is the error I get from the ftp_put operation:
"Warning: ftp_put(): Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted in....."

Could this be a firewall issue? The server is an EC2 instance.
Paddy

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem today. Using

```
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

to enforce passive transfers before the actual call to `ftp_put()` solved the problem for me.